# Does Hinnant's unique_ptr implementation incorrectly fail to convert derived-to-base in this case?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I'm currently trying to use [Howard Hinnant's unique_ptr implementation](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/unique_ptr03.html), and am running into a compile error. Here is some sample code:

```
struct Base {};

struct Derived : public Base {};

void testfun(boost::unique_ptr<Base>);

void test()
{
    unique_ptr<Derived> testDerived; 
    unique_ptr<Base> testBase(move(testDerived)); // ok, construct base explicitly from derived 
    testfun(move(testBase));                      // ok, pass base to testfun which expects base 
    testfun(unique_ptr<Base>(move(testDerived))); // ok, explicitly converts to unique_ptr<Base>
    testfun(move(testDerived));                   // error on this line
}
```

The error I get is

```
In function 'void test()':
error: no matching function for call to 'boost::unique_ptr<Base, boost::default_delete<Base> >::unique_ptr(boost::unique_ptr<Base, boost::default_delete<Base> >)'
note: candidates are: boost::unique_ptr<T, D>::unique_ptr(boost::detail_unique_ptr::rv<boost::unique_ptr<T, D> >) [with T = Base, D = boost::default_delete<Base>]
note:                 boost::unique_ptr<T, D>::unique_ptr(boost::unique_ptr<T, D>&) [with T = Base, D = boost::default_delete<Base>]
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void testfun(boost::unique_ptr<Base, boost::default_delete<Base> >)' from result of 'boost::unique_ptr<T, D>::unique_ptr(boost::unique_ptr<U, E>, typename boost::enable_if_c<((((! boost::is_array<U>::value) && boost::detail_unique_ptr::is_convertible<typename boost::unique_ptr<U, boost::default_delete<U> >::pointer,typename boost::detail_unique_ptr::pointer_type<T, D>::type>::value) && boost::detail_unique_ptr::is_convertible<E,D>::value) && ((! boost::is_reference<D>::value) || boost::is_same<D,E>::value)), void>::type*) [with U = Derived, E = boost::default_delete<Derived>, T = Base, D = boost::default_delete<Base>]'
```

It seems like the offending line should not fail. Is this a bug in the implementation, a limitation of the implementation due to the lack of C++0x language features, or a misunderstanding of the rules of unique_ptrs?

(Note, I know this won't work at run-time because I'm moving the same thing more than once; I'm just trying to figure out the compile-time error.)

Comment: probably the key part of the description is this "This emulation is intended to capture **most** of the behavior of the C++0X unique_ptr...". I think that implies that not all of the behavior is there.

Comment: Here is the paper that led to this behavior of C++03: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2000/n1232.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research has lead me to [this note](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2009/01/146858.php), leading me to believe that this is a known limitation of the implementation:

3 of the tests currently fail for me (fail at compile time,
supposed to compile, run and pass). These are all associated with the
converting constructor specified in [unique.ptr.single.ctor]. When
the source and target are of different type, this emulation demands
that the conversion be explicit, and refuses to compile on implicit
conversions:

```
unique_ptr<base> b(unique_ptr<derived>()); // ok

unique_ptr<base> b = unique_ptr<derived>(); // causes 3 compile time failures under unique.ptr/unique.ptr.single/unique.ptr.single.ctor .
```

Comment: litb's writeup is very informative, but I think this one is a more direct answer to the question. Both should be read by interested parties :-)

Answer (score 1):

For a similar example, see this which should fail too

```
unique_ptr<Base> testBase = move(testDerived);
```

The problem here is how the move semantic is implemented: The "copy constructor" takes a non-const reference, thus not being able to bind to temporaries. To still "move" from temporaries, the class has a conversion function (following are really just conceptual - they may be differently implemented in detail):

```
operator rv<T>() { return rv<T>(*this); }
```

And a constructor will take that object:

```
unique_ptr(rv<T> r):ptr_(r.release()) { }
```

Here is an example that fails for the same reason:

```
// move helper. rv<> in unique_ptr
struct E { };

// simulates a unique_ptr<D>
struct D { };

// simulates the unique_ptr<B>
struct A {
  A() { }

  // accepts "derived" classes. Note that for unique_ptr, this will need that
  // the argument needs to be copied (we have a by-value parameter). Thus we 
  // automatically ensure only rvalue derived-class pointers are accepted.
  A(D) { } 

  // these will accept rvalues
  A(E) { }
  operator E() { return E(); }

private:
  A(A&); // private, error if passed lvalue
};
```

Now, consider this code:

```
// allowed: goes: D -> A(D)
A a((D()));

// compile failure. Goes:
// D -> A(D) -> A(E)
A a = D();
```

Copy initialization will first convert to `A`. But then, the temporary `A` object is tried to be copied again to the final object. This will need the way using `operator E`. But that's another user defined conversion in the initialization, which the standard forbids:

`13.3.3.1/4`

> When invoked for the copying of the temporary in the second step of a class copy-initialization, [...], only standard conversion sequences and ellipsis conversion sequences are allowed.

This is why your code fails.